# The OP switched the accepted answer because the other answerer asked them to

Tags: discussion

I have an odd situation here, where I answered a question and got an acceptance for it.

A few hours later I noticed that the OP changed the accepted answer to another, apparently because they were asked why that answer wasn't the accepted one.

The OP then commented on the other answer with:

> Well either work, I don't even know. Since you have less score, I'll
>   give it to you then.

and then switched accepted answer.

Of course I checked the other answer to see if it had some other solution that would be better than mine, though it hadn't. It actually had an issue which made it not working properly.

I notified the OP and asked why they picked an answer which had a flaw, and they commented back:

> I actually use your version for the page.

As the best interest of this site is to have the best answer for each question, will my question be, how do we handle these kind of events, where a less good answer becomes the accepted one based on the above?

Here is a link to the post in question: [Variable doesn't change with if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32794263/variable-doesnt-change-with-if-statement)

**Update**

Obviously my comment I wrote to the OP paid off, as he switched back to my answer as the accepted one.

**And** then, about 2 hours later, I got a serial downvote issue, 18 answers in 3 min ... who could possibly done that ... did I say that the other answer were deleted as well ......

Comment: It's completely up to the OP which answer they select. In this case it seems they chose poorly, and you can comment telling them as much (with link to the Help Center for rationale, to avoid looking like it's just complaining about lost points), but that's all.

Comment: Well that was exactly what I was doing, which you will see if you read the referenced question.

Comment: So you did. What's your question, then? And why not mention the action you took?

Comment: This kind of thing happens and it's best not to exert too much energy on worrying about it. The final decision which answer gets the check mark is with the OP.

Comment: So when an OP obviously choose an answer which is less good, which he can, and then comments that he switched to give the other answerer the point as he had less, how can that be in this sites interest?

Comment: @LGSon it is not ideal but, again, *the OP gets final say on acceptance*. That's why you should always read beyond the accepted answer when researching, too.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I just asked a simple question, without personal worries, as I think when the issue is as visible as this and couldn't possible be in this site's interest.

Comment: @LGSon, the acceptance check mark is the single exception to the "community's best interests" rule. That check mark only reflects the opinion of the questioner and not much else. In that case, they chose to award it to the answerer with the less reputation, which I've seen happen quite a lot. The questioner probably thinks they did a good deed, I would suggest you do not let that bother you too much.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know OP has final say, I still think, when the issue is as visible as this, it couldn't possible be in this site's interest so I asked about it here.

Comment: But what's the alternative? Accept mark by diktat? From whom, and in which cases? (I do agree that the accept mark is too prominent and suggests "this has been solved" to much)

Comment: @Pekka웃 We have a great feature, "flag a post", which could be used when an issue like this, which is so obvious/visible where an OP actually wrote why he changed. Using this feature would be much better, so someone else than me, who is personal involved, give the poster a comment on why his behavior wasn't proper -- exactly like we can do with abuse or spam poster's

Comment: So what should happen when you flag the post - given that the moderators who respond to it don't necessarily have knowledge in the specific technology? How should they decide whether you have a point, and that the other user needs to be reprimanded? What if the other user had some other reason to change the accept mark, and a huge discussion with moderators ensues? This would take gigantic amounts of moderator time which is precious and limited as it is. It'd be similarly inane as trying to police people's "correct" voting.

Comment: If your answer is better, hopefully voting will reflect that in the long term. What we arguably should do is give the accepted answer less prominence to send the right signals to future generations.

Comment: @Pekka웃 That I agree with .. so why not remove the reputation that comes along with accepting an answer, as it, as you say, not doing any good for future generations ... we still have the voting model which I think is great

Comment: Not sure what removing the reputation gain would improve? After all, that's not really visible on the site. I'd support removing the emphasis that the accept mark currently carries, but it's been suggested before and so far, not been implemented

Comment: Well if you can't earn reputation on the accepted answer, less will chase being the first answerer getting those points and instead be forced to create good answers to earn points, and as the voting speaks actually louder, ....

Comment: Well, given the long comment trail it looks like the OP had a great deal of trouble using your solution.  Nine edits of the post surely did not help.   You can't be that surprised he favored another answer.  The amount of effort you put in an answer is not usually a strong selector for an answer mark.

Comment: @HansPassant Updated my answer ... and if you check the referenced post in question, you might want to delete your comment.

Comment: Hmya, the meta-effect is a multi-headed monster.  You can't count on it every time.

Comment: Don't worry about those [serial downvotes](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4OuTB.png), by the way. Those will be reversed when the system checks for serial voting.

Comment: @Cerbrus Thanks for notifiying

Comment: In any event, the (probably way less than) 1% of people doing bad things will be totally swamped by the other 99% doing the right thing. Trust the swarm, Hari Seldon had the right idea.

Comment: @paxdiablo Learned that now and worry less today :) ... though when I posted this, I just had started my rep. hunt to increase my privileges and didn't want to give in too easy :) ... I mean after all, one need to be right, right ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> As the best interest of this site is to have the best answer for each question, will my question be, how do we handle these kind of events, where a less good answer becomes the accepted one based on the above?

You have to keep in mind what the difference is between up vote and accept.

An up vote still means: the answer is useful. Its usefulness is determined by the community based on how well it answered the question, explains what was wrong in the attempt from the OP and is backed by references. Good answers are flooded with up votes by the community.

The OP can mark an answer that helped him most. They are free to use every criteria they like for that, for example, but not limited to:

- First to answer
- Last to answer
- Copy-paste -> worked
- Additional info
- cuteness of the displayname
- urging comments to accept
- reputation
- Jon Skeet
- roll-a-dice
- best answer

And they are free to change their accept at any moment and they are free to not accept at all.

tl;dr; it is not for us to judge if an OP did choose the best answer as accepted. If the accepted answer is wrong down vote and/or leave comment. Beyond that there is not much that should be done, specially not bothering the OP.

Comment: You forgot [Tim's keys.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/288751)

Comment: No, @TinyGiant that is only for down voting. But I'm sure Tim has yet another epic story to explain why he accepted the wrong answer ....

Comment: What, Tim losing his keys can't also cause someone to slip and click accept on the other answer without noticing?

Comment: @TinyGiant: No, that is totally unrealistic ;)

Comment: Ah, so *that* explains why Skeet has so much more rep than me. I thought it was merit-based but, obviously, it's because his name is so much cooler. Whew, my cognitive dissonance wins yet again :-)